# Python: Unexpected behaviour of nonlocal variable in recursion

Tags: python, recursion, short-circuiting, python-nonlocal

The following code is expected to set the nonlocal variable `flag` to true after 3 calls to `recur()`. I expect `flag` in the following code to be always true after `recur(2)` returns (starting from 0)

```py
def f():
    flag = False
    def recur(n):
        nonlocal flag
        print(f"this is recur {n}")
        print("flag is: ", flag)
        if n == 2: 
            print(f"end of recur {n}")
            print("flag is: ", flag)
            return True
        flag = flag or recur(n+1) # the culprit line
        
        print(f"end of recur {n}")
        print("flag is: ", flag)
        return False
    recur(0)
f()
```

However, `flag` jumps from true to false when recur(1) returns. The output of the function is as follow:

```
this is recur 0 
flag is: False 
this is recur 1 
flag is: False 
this is recur 2 
flag is: False 
end of recur 2 
flag is: False 
end of recur 1 
flag is: True 
end of recur 0 
flag is: False <-- I expect this to be true
```

When I change the culprit line to `flag = recur(n+1) or flag`, the code works as expected, i.e. `flag` will always be true after recur(2) returns.

I suspect it has something to do with short-circuiting of `or`, but still I am totally confused. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `flag = flag or recur(n+1)`, the LHS of the `or` is evaluated before `recur(n+1)`. When `recur(0)` executes this line, it evaluates `flag` and gets `False` before calling `recur(1)`.

By the time `recur(1)` returns, `flag` is `True`, but the LHS of the `or` has already been evaluated, so the `or` evaluates `False or False` and gets `False`, not `True`.

Short-circuiting would also come into play if the LHS of the `or` was evaluated as `True`, but that never happens in this code.

Comment: Thank you! This is crystal clear! Do you have any recommendation where I can read about this evaluation procedure?

Comment: @stackUnderflow: Not really. There's the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), but it's kind of a dense read.